# Ranking MySQL query results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
name | score
asdf | 50
zxcv | 100
qwer | 80
aaa  | 70
.
.
.
```

and I could obtain someone's ranking via this query:

```
SELECT(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM leaderboard m2
WHERE m2.score >= m1.score
) as rank,name,score
FROM leaderboard m1
WHERE name='aaa'
```

and this query would give me something like this:

```
rank | name | score
  3  | aaa  |  70
```

The problem is the result I want to see with name='aaa' is like this :

```
rank | name | score
  2  | qwer |  80
  3  | aaa  |  70
  4  | asdf |  50
```

(with aaa's ranking and the around of aaa's result)

How could it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ROW\_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: Please do research on mysql and ranking. Plenty of Q&A on this site

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 0):

My self-conclusion on this issue :

`SELECT(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM leaderboard m2
WHERE m2.score >= m1.score
) as rank,name,score
FROM leaderboard m1
WHERE
(SELECT
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM leaderboard m2
WHERE m2.score >= m1.score
)
as rank
)>=(
SELECT(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM leaderboard m2
WHERE m2.score >= m1.score
)
as rank
FROM leaderboard m1
WHERE name = 'AAA'
) - 5
ORDER BY rank
LIMIT 0,10`